# What is the ratio of the volume of the pyramid to the volume of the cube?

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

> A sphere is inscribed inside a pyramid with a square as a base whose height is $15$ times the length
>   of one edge of the base. A cube is inscribed inside the sphere. What is the ratio of the volume of the pyramid to the volume of the cube?

**Official solution**[image]

**Question** The problem never mentions the side lengths of the pyramid, only the height. Therefore how can the solution conclude that the plane cut is isosceles?

Comment: Is it because the pyramid is inscribable with a sphere? That leads to the question of where it is possible to inscribe a sphere inside a square pyramid that isn't equilateral?